# The equivalent of C# consuming a WCF method in JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf

I have a running WCF service that exposes a method *GetStuff(String type)*. It's called by the automatically created client class, so the syntax is embarrassingly simple.

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
String response = client.GetStuff("other's");
client.Close();
```

The straight-forward question is this. **How do I convert that to a call in JavaScript (possiblyusing jQuery) in an easy way?**

After some serious googling, I concluded that I'm only going to find examples of how to consume a JSON-formatted stream using jQuery. I prefer not to touch the service-side of the software, if at all possible.

I tried the code below (along with a bunch of derivatives that I could think of) but the error I got was "*No Transport*" and googling that didn't yield anything that I got me going.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://hazaa.azurewebsites.net/Service.svc",
  success: function (response) { console.info(response); },
  error: function (response) { console.error("Error! " + response.statusText); }
});
```

Will I have to write a totally different service that exposes the data in JSON format? How do I specify that the service is supposed to call this or that method? Am I out of luck and these convenience methods are for .NET clients only?

Please note that I've got another way of getting the data where I want, not using JavaScript at all but I'd prefer to see if this is (easily) doable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert server method to use web invocation = WebInvoke attribute. Here you can specify uri for the method call.

[Link to the info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Two questions arise - should I change *WebGet* to *WebInvoke* or keep both? Also, more important - is that sufficient to use the JavaScript I quoted in my question? The article doesn't give any JS example...

Comment: You could keep WebGet. With Webinvoke, you could also use get verb, but you have to specify it. This should be sufficient to call the method using get. Also specify uri template. And you can also specify the format of a message. Try this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call)

Comment: Ir sort-of solved the issue. Apparently, due to CORS (different origins), I'll have to use JSONP, so I'm getting the impression that I need to implement yet an other method on the server-side and that exposing an endpoint isn't enough... Right I I'm disliking JS a little bit more.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into Jquery SOAP .. http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/ etc.
haven't tried it myself but it's the kind of thing you might be needing here.